# Asynchronous display of map point data

Tags: django, asynchronous, leaflet

I want to implement a asynchronous interaction in my django web map app. I display a set of opoints (using leaflet). What I want to do is to create a view function call on a mouseover event to get and display some data of a given point. I had a look at the
[dajaxproject](http://www.dajaxproject.com) which looks promising. Does anyone know of better solution? Any experience sharing is highly appreciated.